# List of even numbers at even number indexes using list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to generate an even numbered list at even index locations using a list comprehension. The else values will be `0`. I have done the function which does the same as below

```
def even_list(l):
  ll = []
  for x in l:
     if x%2 == 0:
       ll.append(x)
       ll.append(0)
  return ll[:-1]
```

Now I need to turn this into a list comprehension.

```
input = [11, 17, 12, 17, 40, 19, 12, 16]    
out = [12, 0, 40, 0, 12, 0, 16]
```

This is what I have tried (`l` is input and `lo` is out):

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> lo = []
>>> lo = [l[x] if l[x]%2 == 0 and len(lo)%2 == 0 else 0 for x in range(len(l))]
>>> print lo
[0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0]
```

Comment: Could you please add input / expected output?

Comment: did you forget an `else:` in your code?

Comment: Have you seen `xrange(0,end,2)`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yeah I know it is not, I am trying to pose a problem which I am not able to solve, fully within the rules of SO.

Comment: @RohitSrivastava you appear to have made precisely zero effort to implement a list comp, so I disagree. And if what you have works, **why** do you *"need to turn [it] into list comprehension [sic]"*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe well I have made lots of effort about it and I did not succeed, thats why this question is.

Comment: @RohitSrivastava so *where's that effort*? There's no sign of it in the question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe added the closest possible effort.

Comment: @RohitSrivastava thanks! And what precisely is wrong with it? Was that the same `l` as `input`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it will unlikely help other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to figure out exactly what you were looking for from your post, but here's what I think you want:

Given a list, get all the numbers at even indices. If any of these numbers are even, put them in a new list and return it:

```
In [10]: L = [3,1,54,5,2,3,4,5,6,5,2,5,3,2,5,2,2,5,2,5,2]

In [11]: [num for i,num in enumerate(L) if not num%2 and not i%2]
Out[11]: [54, 2, 4, 6, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

If you want to add `0`s in between, then you can do a little `itertools` magic:

```
In [12]: list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip((num for i,num in enumerate(L) if not num%2 and not i%2), itertools.cycle([0]))))[:-1]
Out[12]: [54, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2]
```

Ok, that was a lot of brackets and parentheses, so let's take a closer look at it:

1. `list(...)[:-1]` converts `...` into a `list` and gets all but the last element of that list. This is similar to what you were trying to do when you added `0`s and removed the last one
2. `(num for i,num in enumerate(L) if not num%2 and not i%2)` is the same as what it was before the edit, except that it uses parentheses (`()`) instead of brackets (`[]`). This turns it into a generator-comprehension, as opposed to a list comprehension - it only matters in that it performs a little bit of optimization - the values are not computed until they are needed (until `zip` asks for the next value)
3. `itertools.cycle([0])` gives an endless list of `0`s
4. `zip(A, B)` returns a list of tuples, in which the `i`th tuple has two elements - the `i`th element of `A`, and the `i`th element of `B`
5. `itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(A, B))` returns the elements of `A` and `B` interleaved, as a generator. In essence, it's like doing this:

```
def someFunc(A, B):
    for i in range(len(A)):
        yield A[i]
        yield B[i]
```

Thus, all of these put together give you exactly what you want

Comment: Thanks I was trying the same but I need to append 0 in the out list at the odd indexes . That was a little challenging for me. Added the Input and out

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: x if x % 2 == 0 else 0, range(10)))
[0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0]
```

`range(10)` generates a list with integers from 0 to 9.
To this list I apply a map, which transforms all odd numbers in the list into 0, and doesn't do anything with the even numbers (`lambda x: x if x % 2 == 0 else 0`).

Then I cast this map back into a list to get a nice print.

Comment: Mind to explain this a bit?

Comment: I've added some details :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this based on your expected output.But you must know `list comprehension` is nothing more or less than `for loop`.

```
input = [11, 17, 12, 17, 40, 19, 12, 16] 
>>>[k for j in [[i,0] for i in input if i%2 == 0] for k in j][:-1]
[12, 0, 40, 0, 12, 0, 16]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> [x if x%2 == 0 else 0 for x in range(20)]
[0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0, 10, 0, 12, 0, 14, 0, 16, 0, 18, 0]
```